# how can i make zoom like in google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer

im developing a game with some game field, which is drawn in some view. My game field always drawing relative to his center, so i have just simple pinch

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
    (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
    self.gameBoardGridView.scale *= gesture.scale; // adjust our scale

    gesture.scale = 1;  
}
```

and pan

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
CGPoint translatedPoint = [recognizer translationInView:self.gameBoardGridView];


self.gameBoardGridView.gridCenter = CGPointMake(self.gameBoardGridView.gridCenter.x + translatedPoint.x, self.gameBoardGridView.gridCenter.y + translatedPoint.y);

[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.gameBoardGridView];
}
```

but i need other kind of zoom. When you put two fingers down and then move one of them, the field expands (zooms in) like it should, but the pixels under the fingers are no longer under the finger. The image scales from the center of the image, not the mid point between the two fingers.

I tried a lot of examples, but nothing works like i want. Finally i wrote this, it works almost correct, but not completely

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
CGFloat curScale = gesture.scale;

static CGPoint startPoint;

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    startPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.gameBoardGridView];
}


if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
    (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
    self.gameBoardGridView.scale *= gesture.scale;

    CGFloat widthDelta = self.gameBoardGridView.gridWidth * fabs(gesture.scale - 1) / 3;
    CGFloat heightDelta = self.gameBoardGridView.gridHeight * fabs(gesture.scale - 1) / 3;


    gesture.scale = 1;

    CGPoint lastPoint = self.gameBoardGridView.gridCenter;

    const CGFloat epsilon = 5;

    CGFloat coef = 1.0;
    if(curScale < 1) {
        coef = -1.0;
    }

    if (startPoint.x + epsilon < self.view.frame.size.width / 2) {
            lastPoint.x += widthDelta*coef;
    }
    else if (startPoint.x - epsilon > self.view.frame.size.width / 2) {
            lastPoint.x -= widthDelta*coef;
    }

    if (startPoint.y + epsilon < self.view.frame.size.height / 2) {
            lastPoint.y += heightDelta*coef;
    }
    else if (startPoint.y - epsilon > self.view.frame.size.height / 2) {
            lastPoint.y -= heightDelta*coef;
    }


    self.gameBoardGridView.gridCenter = lastPoint;
}
}
```

May be there is other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The center of the zoom is to the image's anchor point.
What you have to do is to change the anchor point to the middle point of your fingers, the location, and position.
Didn't tried it myself buy I saw a complete solution here, maybe it will help you -

https://github.com/robertblackwood/CCPanZoomController

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `UIScrollView`? I did something similar. I started using this tutorial and then I added some specific code for my app.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content